# PyDev remote debugging not working (connection refused)

Tags: python, eclipse, pydev, remote-debugging

I'm using Eclipse Luna Service Release 1 (4.4.1) with PyDev 3.9.0.201411111611 for Python 2.7 development, on an ArchLinux (Manjaro) machine.

I have an external script to run my application from command line, using the `import pydevd; pydevd.settrace()` template as described in the [docs](http://pydev.org/manual_adv_remote_debugger.html) for remote debugging.

The full script is as follows:

```
#!/usr/bin/python2
import sys

sys.path.append('/home/manu343726/Documentos/myapp/')
sys.path.append('/home/manu343726/.eclipse/org.eclipse.platform_4.4.1_1543616141_linux_gtk_x86_64/plugins/org.python.pydev_3.9.0.201411111611/pysrc/')

from mymodule import main

try:
    import pydevd;pydevd.settrace()
except Exception as e:
    print e
    print ">>>>>>>>ERROR!!! Could not attach to python debugger"

print "*"*50
print "running myapp from source"
print "*"*50
main(sys.argv[1:])
```

With this settup when I call myapp from command line no exception is thrown from `settrace()`, but the script halts on that line and after a couple of minutes refuses the connection to the server. This is the complete traceback:

```
Could not connect to 127.0.0.1: 5678
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/manu343726/.eclipse/org.eclipse.platform_4.4.1_1543616141_linux_gtk_x86_64/plugins/org.python.pydev_3.9.0.201411111611/pysrc/pydevd_comm.py", line 484, in StartClient
    s.connect((host, port))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 224, in meth
    return getattr(self._sock,name)(*args)
error: [Errno 111] Connection refused
```

The PyDev remote debugger is correctly started inside Eclipse, at localhost using the port 5678.

**Is there something I'm doing wrong?**

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem and eclipse was not able to get to the python debugger after I upgraded Aptana and pydev.

I had to open a firewall port on my Ubuntu 14.04 machine.

While this is not the best way, things started working again.

sudo ufw allow 5678

Builtin's were also being highlighted before I did this, now pydev is able to resolve such things as True, max and None.